# Animating large text across screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I have large text going across the screen like this:

```js
var bkgrndString = "This is a string";
var r = 1;
playBackground();

function playBackground() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("bkgrnd")[0].innerHTML = bkgrndString.substring(0, r);
  setTimeout(function() {
    r++;
    if (r <= bkgrndString.length) {
      playBackground();
    }
  }, 800);

};
```

```css
.bkgrnd {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 1280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<p class="bkgrnd"><p>
```

How can I add in animations so that the chunk of large text glides smoothly across the screen?

I've tried using keyframes so that the entire string exists at once (rather than being typed out over time), but I'm unsure how to create the desired effect.

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa

Comment: Answers go down there, Ben.

Comment: Thanks so much! One more question: how do you get the text to start on the right side of span (starting from displaying the first letter of the string)? Currently it displays the entire string in the div, then begins the animation.

Comment: Just good to know, that you can achieve the same effect using `<marquee>Content</marquee>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee